# I have to reverse a string but my code is not producing any output -- C++

Tags: c++, string, reverse

Given a string S as input. I have to reverse the given string.

Input: First line of input contains a single integer T which denotes the number of test cases. T test cases follows, first line of each test case contains a string S.

Output: Corresponding to each test case, print the string S in reverse order.

why my code is not producing any output?
I did this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
      string s;
      int j=0;
      string res;
      cin>>s;
      int l=s.length();
      for(int i=l-1;i>=0;i--)
      {
         res[j]=s[i];
         j++;
      }
      cout<<res<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input:

1

geeks

output:

Comment: Use [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) or just iterate from `.rbegin()` to `.rend()`.

Comment: "question link:" - No. Don't do that. Stackoverflow questions should be *self contained*, everything needed should be *in the question*. External links rot over time.

Comment: @JesperJuhl can I copy-paste the question statements or I should rephrase the question in my own language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string` is not resized automatically, that's why `res[j]=...` doesn't work.

To fix this you can:

- replace `res[j]=...` with `res.push_back(...)`
- specify string size beforehand, e.g. replace `string res;` with `string res(s.size(), '\0');`

Also note that in production it would be better to do:

```
string res = s;
std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
```

**UPDATE.** As @Blastfurnace pointed out, an even better version would be:

```
std::string res(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
```

Comment: You can also just construct a revered string `std::string res(s.rbegin(), s.rend());`

Comment: Indeed. Updated the answer.